# Compute gradient between a scalar and vector in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, theano

I am trying to replicate code which was written using Theano, to PyTorch. In the code, the author computes the gradient using

```
import theano.tensor as T    
gparams = T.grad(cost, params)
```

and the shape of `gparams` is `(256, 240)`

I have tried using `backward()` but it doesn't seem to return anything. Is there an equivalent to `grad` within PyTorch?

Assume this is my input,

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable 
cost = torch.tensor(1.6019)
params = Variable(torch.rand(1, 73, 240))
```

Comment: param is not in the computation graph when you call cost.backward(). You need some how connect param and cost.

Answer (score 1):

`cost` needs to be a result of an operation involving `params`. You can't compute a gradient just knowing the values of two tensors. You need to know the relationship as well. This is why pytorch builds a computation graph when you perform tensor operations. For example, say the relationship is

```
cost = torch.sum(params)
```

then we would expect the gradient of `cost` with respect to `params` to be a vector of ones regardless of the value of `params`.

That could be computed as follows. Notice that you need to add the `requires_grad` flag to indicate to pytorch that you want `backward` to update the gradient when called.

```
# Initialize independent variable. Make sure to set requires_grad=true.
params = torch.tensor((1, 73, 240), requires_grad=True)

# Compute cost, this implicitly builds a computation graph which records
# how cost was computed with respect to params.
cost = torch.sum(params)

# Zero the gradient of params in case it already has something in it.
# This step is optional in this example but good to do in practice to
# ensure you're not adding gradients to existing gradients.
if params.grad is not None:
    params.grad.zero_()

# Perform back propagation. This is where the gradient is actually
# computed. It also resets the computation graph.
cost.backward()

# The gradient of params w.r.t to cost is now stored in params.grad.
print(params.grad)
```

Result:

```
tensor([1., 1., 1.])
```